# Swagger basic authorization not working with @Api annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Swagger basic authorization not working with @Api annotation .But when used with @Apioperation it is working fine . I want to apply basic authorization at controller level rather than at method level .

used like this :

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
@Api(value="API related ",authorizations = {@Authorization(value="basicAuth")})
@RequestMapping(value="invoices",produces =MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class InvoiceController {


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @GetMapping
    @ApiOperation(value = "${InvoiceController.getAll.notes}", notes="${InvoiceController.getAll.notes}",response = Invoice.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = {@ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully retrieved list of invoices")})
    public  @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Response> getAll(@Valid PaginationDto pagination,@Valid InvoiceFilterCriteriaDto filter) 
                    throws GenericServiceException{

}


}
```

in main class , created Docket like below by mentioning the basic auth :

```
        List<SecurityScheme> schemeList = new ArrayList<>();
        schemeList.add(new BasicAuth("basicAuth"));


        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .forCodeGeneration(true)
                .produces(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList( new String[] { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE.toString()})))
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .securitySchemes(schemeList)
```

Comment: show us the code first !

Comment: added the code for swagger

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding securityContexts to Docket config.

Please refer to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-swagger-jwt